# rails model associations recorded in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have an application with 3 models `user` `company` and `post`.

I'm having trouble with figuring out the logic

A user can have many companies and a company can have many posts.

here are my models

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end

class company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
end

class post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Note: company has user_id, post has company_id in table

how do I make sure when creating a post the company_id is automatically recorded

extra information: for routes it will be `resources :jobs` and `resources :companies`

--update--

post controller

```
def new
 Post.new(post_params)
end
def create
 Post.new(post_params)
 if @post.save
  redirect_to @post
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

routes

```
resources :companies
resources :posts
```

Comment: Can you post your `create` method in your `posts_controller` as well as your routes.rb for posts and companies.

Comment: updated with the information

Comment: how do you pick which company to attach the post to ? is there a company picker in the form?

Answer (score 1):

I think I would probably nest `posts` within `companies`, so you would have available to you the `company_id` in the parameters.

*Note* your path names will change if you do this.

*Routes.rb*

```
resources :companies do
  resources :posts
end
```

*posts_controller.rb*

```
def create
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @post = @company.posts.build(post_params)
  ...
end
```

And since you will want to find the company on each of these actions in the controller, you can refactor it a bit.

```
class PostsController
  before_action :set_company

  def index
    @post = @company.posts
  end

  def create
    @post = @company.posts.build(post_params)
    ...
  end

  ...
  ...

  private

  def set_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: it's a good way, as I mentioned in my answer, but making that  extra request on every action might be a bit of an overkill, especially if the `@company` contains lots of information, wich is not really necessery for the posts.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I think it's a lot cleaner and sets up the foundation moving forward if the OP were to add more under `companies`.

Comment: I think both solutions are great and @company will make things easier going forward

Comment: I'm not questioning the nested resources approach, I'm kust questioning the necesserity of that `set_company` on before_action instead of just setting the `company_id` in one line in `create`. It does not need to go anywhere else then that)

Answer (score 0):

2 options come to mind.

1. You can create a hidden `company_id` field in your `posts#new` view, so it would be sent automatically along with your params and hence be set in the model accordingly (provided that you permit it). But in that case you'll need to populate that field in the controller when creating the `@post`. Just like this:

   ```
   @post = Post.new(company_id: some_company_id)
   ```
2. Use nested resources.First of all change your routes to this:

   ```
   resources :companies do 
     resoures :posts
   end
   ```

   That way when you look at the `rake routes` output you'll see the `:company_id` param being set in the request url. So when you go on creating a post, you can do `@post.company_id = params[:company_id]` and you're done.